# OpenVPN not redirecting

Tags: vpn, routing, openvpn

I've tried to follow [the official documentation](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#redirect), but I can't seem to get it to work.

In my /etc/openvpn/server.conf I have

```
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

set and I have run `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE` to NAT traffic via the Eth0 (which ifconfig says is my default gateway).

After this I restart the openvpn daemon by `sudo service openvpn restart`.

But it seems like my client devices are not able to connect to Internet when connected to my server. If I comment out the above lines from the server.conf file everything seems to work just fine (except that the traffic is not redirected). So it seems like I can connect to my OpenVPN server but have a problem redirecting.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need collect and post more data.  For example when a client is connected with that option what does your route table.  What happens when you do a traceroute for 8.8.8.8?  If you do a tcpdump on tun device on the VPN server what do you see when you do something simple on the client like trying to ping 8.8.8.8?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes 'redirect-gateway def1' doesn't actually work when configured server-side (i.e. as a  'push' option). Try configuring that setting client-side (I.e. in your client config, make a new line called redirect-gateway def1).

I'm not sure why it does this, (maybe a miss-configuration?), but in any case, that should do the trick.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Exactly how would that line look? I can only find `redirect-gateway` for server side in the documentation...

Comment: I added `redirect-gateway def1` (nothing else) in client.conf, but my life was not bettered.